# MKMapView leak according to Instruments

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, mkmapview, mkannotationview

When I use MKMapView, I get a leak according to Instruments.  My code is the following:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
mapView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:mapView];
```

We dealloc the mapview; and the following code is for MKAnnotationView:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    WeatherItem *weatherItem = (WeatherItem *)annotation;
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    WeatherAnnotationView *annotationView = (WeatherAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[WeatherAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    SWPeripheryIndicator *perpheryIndicator = [[SWPeripheryCache sharedPeripheryCache] onePeripheryCityInfo:[weatherItem cityCode]];
    if (perpheryIndicator==nil && MKMapRectContainsPoint(map.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate))) 
    {
        [[SWeatherEngine sharedSWeatherEngine] getPeriphyWeather:weatherItem.cityCode];
        [onDownLoadView setObject:annotationView forKey:weatherItem.cityCode];
    }


    annotationView.cityCode = weatherItem.cityCode;
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    [annotationView updatePeripheryInfo:weatherItem.cityName shouldDisplayData:perpheryIndicator];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: You are leaking the mapView. As you add it to your view, it will be retained. So you have two retains. Use Build&analyze to have a more detailed comment, rather than instruments.

Comment: For the annotations, I don't see obvious leaks. There's one init and it's balanced with an autorelease.  B&A is your friend and a very valuable tool (although it won't catch everything).

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I also don't know where I have a leak.